# eslint issue with jsx-a11y/media-has-caption

Tags: html, jsx, eslint, html5-audio, linter

I have an audio file that im querying from contentful but instead of display the data I keep getting this eslintrule pop, It's an audio file so it has no captions. Is there a way of disabling this or correctly disabling it ?

this is the code

```
{data.allContentfulPodcast.edges.map(video => 
          <div>
          <audio key={video} src={video.node.video.file.url}/>
         
         
          </div>
          )}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to disable that rule for the file by adding this comment at the top:

```js
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/media-has-caption */
```

Comment: lint rules exist for a reason, I don't feel this is a false warning. Disabling doesn't solve the issue

Comment: The question was how to disable the rule, so this is how. Lint warnings aren't perfect and there are valid reasons to disable them. Perhaps it's a pet project where accessibility isn't a concern? In my case, it was false positives on iirc React components that don't actually support captions. Another example would be business rules needing to export a function with a different naming style from the rest of the repo - you can temporarily disable then re-enable rules for that section of code.

Comment: oh shit, he's not looking to solve it. lol

Answer (score 0):

You can also add rule to disable that specific line:

```
{data.allContentfulPodcast.edges.map(video => 
        <div>
          /* eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/media-has-caption */
          <audio key={video} src={video.node.video.file.url}/>
       </div>
)}
```